# Genetic algorithm to maximize a function $\text{Sinc}(x)$

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can one use a [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) to calculate the maximum value of this function `Sin[x] / x` function (`Sinc[x]` in *Mathematica*)?

Comment: What is the name of the genetic algorithm? Please share some code in your post.

Comment: [http://www.husseinsspace.com/research/publications/gpinmath.pdf] should get you started with genetic algorithms and mathemtica, but I don't know if it is fit for your application.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do so many different things for crossover and mutation, like toggling/interchanging bits in the binary representation of $x$ or whatever - but here I've just used an average for crossover, and some progressively weakening noise for mutation which gradually reduces with the variance.

```
f[x_] := Sinc[x] (* sin(x) / x *)
fitness[x_] := f[x]

(* Take the n most fit items from pop *)
selection[pop_, n_] := TakeLargestBy[pop, fitness, n]

(* crossover function is just the average *)
cross[a_, b_] := (a + b)/2.
randompair[list_] := RandomSample[list, 2]
(* crossover takes sz many random pairs and applies cross to them *)
crossover[list_, sz_] := cross @@@ Table[randompair@list, sz]

(* as variance goes down, decrease the amount of mutation *)
mut[x_, var_] := x + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt@var]]
mutate[list_] := With[{var = Variance@list}, mut[#, var] & /@ list]

ge[pop_, n_] := mutate@crossover[#, Length@pop] &@selection[pop, n]

SeedRandom[1];
plt = Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}];
popsize = 50;
allowedtocross = 10;
iterations = 5;
results = NestList[ge[#, allowedtocross] &, 
                   RandomReal[{-10, 10}, popsize], 
                   iterations];

Animate[
 Show[plt, 
  ListPlot[{#, f[#]} & /@ results[[i]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> 0]],
 {i, 1, Length@results, 1}
]
```

[image: anim ge]

Comment: I hope this question is reopened considering how good of an answer there was to the question. (an answer with 8 upvotes and accepted answer to me i think suggests the question is good)

Comment: @StevenSagona I still think it should remain closed. There's nothing special about this answer, as I've stopped short of analyzing performance and exploring other options. The question lacks detail and requirements for a good answer.